# Redirect to created entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, web

Good day)
There is a controller, upon successful completion an entity will be created, I want that after submitting the form, a redirect to the page of this entity occurs, but its id is currently not known)
Tell me, who knows how to redirect to an created entity?

```
@PostMapping("/project/create")
public String processCreateProject(
        @Valid Project project,
        BindingResult bindingResult,
        Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("project", project);
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        Map<String, String> errors = ControllerUtils.getErrors(bindingResult);
        model.mergeAttributes(errors);
        return "teacherProjectCreate";
    } else {
        projectService.createProject(project);
        return "redirect:/projects/project/{id}";
    }
}
```

Where {id} in "redirect:/projects/project/{id}" - is the id of the created entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make changes in the method to return the id of Newly created project and redirect on that Id.

```
Long id = projectService.createProject(project);
```

And then populate the ID in the redirection url like below.

```
"redirect:/projects/project/"+id;
```